# Getting error "E/bt_btif:... ignore HID..." using Android BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I'm trying to send data from my wearable device pushing a button to send a value to my phone but when I push the button I get the following error:

```
E/bt_btif: bta_gattc_process_indicate, ignore HID ind/notificiation
```

I'm using the code disposed in this [tutorial](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-communicate-with-a-custom-ble-using-an-android-app/). 
Do you know how to solve it?

Thank you in advance. 
Regards!

Answer (score 1):

I could Imagine there's a problem between the app and the service that the BLE device, assuming The IDBLUE device is configured using the Bluetooth HID driver as an input device that can only send specific tag information of the first successful tag scanned as text output when the Action Button is pressed. Because the device is not configurable over Bluetooth and operates similar to a keyboard wedge, it doesn’t need extra development time for integration.

But you should return to the device Services and ensures that Services & UUIDs are correct and the device is working properly. for Now I could help with a BLE example I have developed to send & receive data from BLE HC-10 BLE Module and tested with Arduino and works pretty fine.  It should be the same idea of the tutorial you went with it and you could change the UUIDs to the one of your device. 
the Android app Link is there : https://github.com/Waged/BLEArduino

Comment: Hi and thank you for you response.

I use your code and it's awesome it does that I need.

So my device has a buzzer and a button, I'm trying to make my buzzer "beep" when I push a button on your app, and do a toast on the app when I push the button on the device.

The developer of the device give me the following information:

Checksum = type + content (read and write)
Checksum:0xaa
Content: 0x05 Phone find the My tag 
Content: 0x03 Level one alarm 

Software protocols:
Service UUID   0xfff0
Feature UUID   0xfff1 (write and read)
Feature UUID   0xfff2 (notification)

Comment: This is the code that the developer give me:

https://github.com/AXAET/AXAMyTag---Android--SDK/blob/master/MyTag/MyTagelibrary/src/com/comime/swdevice/UUIDUtils.java

Could you please help me to use it?

Thank you again.

Regards.